# How to split a string into 2 arrays Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, string, int, swift4

For example i have an array like that :

> var array = ["Hello", "World", "1" , "2"]

How can i split it into 2 arrays? One have string value and one have int value like that

> arrayStr = ["Hello", "World"]
>
> array Int = ["1", "2"]

Comment: `arrayStr = ["Hello", "World"]` or `arrayStr = ["Hello, World"]`? That's really different (same question for the "int" one).

Comment: thank for comment. i edited already

Comment: what is the criteria for splitting a `[String]`? is it about whether the value _may be_ a numeric value?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Try this and see*: Use `loop` with `if-let` or `if-is` condition to identify data type of array element and append into relevant array.

Here is test example:

```
let array = ["Hello", "World ", "1" , "2"]

var arrayStr = [String]()
var arrayInt = [Int]()


for arrayElement in array {

    if let intValue = Int(arrayElement) {
        arrayInt.append(intValue)
    }  else {
        arrayStr.append(arrayElement)
    }
}

print("arrayStr - \(arrayStr)")
print("arrayInt - \(arrayInt)")
```

**Result:**

> arrayStr - ["Hello", "World"]
>   
> arrayInt - [1, 2]

[image]

Comment: This won't work as the car in the else statement will never create ints. arrayInt will be empty for the given array, as it contains only strings — of which some might be used to instantiate Ints from. But a cast just won't work.

Comment: `let intValue = arrayElement as? Int` this will NOT work as intended, now all items will go in the arrayStr.

Comment: check here to see that this code does not work as intended: https://gist.github.com/tweedeviking/5abf77d2222bda17824290b519e469cf

Comment: So now you have the exact same solution as [Moe Abdul-Hameed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47573726/106435) — only difference is that he uses an `forEach` call where you use iterating with a for loop. So no real difference at all.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter if a string can be used to create an int:

```
let array = ["Hello", "World", "1" , "2"]

let intArray = array.filter { (string) -> Bool in
    return Int(string) != nil
}
```

and if not, you treat it as string

```
let stringArray = array.filter { (string) -> Bool in
    return Int(string) == nil
}
```

Result:

```
print(stringArray)
print(intArray)
```

will print

```
["Hello", "World"]
["1", "2"]
```

If the intArry indeed should. contain Ints, and not strings representing the Int, you can use map.

```
let intArray = array.filter { (string) -> Bool in
    return Int(string) != nil
}.map { return Int($0)!}
```

---

Shortened code:

```
let array = ["Hello", "World", "1" , "2"]
let stringArray = array.filter { Int($0) == nil }
let intArray = array.flatMap (Int.init)
```

Comment: "filter + map == flatMap" → `let intArray = array.flatMap (Int.init)`

Comment: This needs 2 passes over `array` in order to achieve the goal, right?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed: Well, I don't expect an iOS app to handle arrays with hundreds of millions items. So a concise and compact syntax if to be preferred. Also with my approach all involved arrays can be `let` constants. and immutability takes away a whole class of possible errors. Or in Knuth's words: [«Premature optimization is the root of all evil»](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/05/16/premature-optimization-is-the-root-of-all-evil/)

Comment: @vikingosegundo Good point of view, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**One pass solution,** You can do it this way:

```
var intArray = [Int]()
var stringArray = [String]()
array.forEach {
    if let integer = Int($0) {
        intArray.append(integer)
    } else {
        stringArray.append($0)
    }
}

print(intArray) // [1, 2]
print(stringArray) // ["Hello", "World"]
```

All we did here is that we created 2 empty arrays, one for `Int`s and one for `String`s.

Then we iterated over the values of the main array, and if we were able to cast the value to `Int` then it is an `Int` and we should add it to `intArray`. And if not, we'll add it to `stringArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this by only checking the condition once. It uses `reduce` to split the array into two arrays.

```
let sepArray = array.reduce(([String](), [Int]()), {
    if let int = Int($1) {
        return ($0.0, $0.1 + [int])
    } else {
        return ($0.0 + [$1], $0.1)
    }
})
sepArray //(["Hello", "World"], [1, 2])
```

You can also use this generically. For this approach, you pass in a condition that tries to map your element to a new type. It moves every element where the condition returns not nil into a second array.

```
extension Array {
    func separateElements<T>(where condition: (Element) -> T?) -> ([Element], [T]) {
        return self.reduce(([Element](), [T]()), {
            if let elementToSeparate = condition($1) {
                return ($0.0, $0.1 + [elementToSeparate])
            } else {
                return ($0.0 + [$1], $0.1)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

You can use it like this.

```
array.separateElements(where: { Int($0) }) //(["Hello", "World"], [1, 2])
```